# Why does unloaded event of window do not fire in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I have created a window and show it as a dialog by calling it by the method ShowDialog(). But when I close the window by Close() method the Unloaded event is not fired for this dialog window.

```
MyWindow obj = new MyWindow(); 
obj.ShowDialog();
obj.Close();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a known issue.

Use this instead

```
   yourWindow.Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted += Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted;

   private void Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
       //do what you want to do on closing
   }
```

Read [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/06/23/dispose-of-a-wpf-usercontrol-ish.aspx) for more details

**Edit**

If above is not working try this

```
yourWindow.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(YourWindow_Closing);

void YourWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: This event too is not firing after obj.Close(). It is only firing when the whole application is closed.

Comment: Yes. I have created Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted += Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted; in the constructor of the dialog window and written its event in the function as given above.

Comment: Yes the updated answer is working ! For it we have to use System.ComponentModel. Thanks :). But I still wonder why did not the Window.Unloaded() or Dispather.ShutdownStarted() did not work. Is it because the window was used as dialog ?

Comment: I am still confused about this behaviour but on googling I found ou people suggest going for closing event to be on safe side. Unloaded might be skipped in some cases. At this time I still don't know why

Answer (score 10):

if you really want to get confirmation of closing i think its best to understand the life-cycle of a window and the relevant events it raises.

However the in my opinion the best source of confirmation is the `Closed` Event. Other framework ways maybe unreliable

## Closing Events

When a window closes, it raises two events: [Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing) and [Closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closed).

> Closing is raised before the window closes, and it provides a
>   mechanism by which window closure can be prevented. One common reason
>   to prevent window closure is if window content contains modified data.
>   In this situation, the Closing event can be handled to determine
>   whether data is dirty and, if so, to ask the user whether to either
>   continue closing the window without saving the data or to cancel
>   window closure. The following example shows the key aspects of
>   handling Closing.

**Further more**

> The Closing event handler is passed a CancelEventArgs, which
>   implements the BooleanCancel property that you set to true to prevent
>   a window from closing. +
>
> If Closing is not handled, or it is handled but not canceled, the
>   window will close. Just before a window actually closes, Closed is
>   raised. At this point, a window cannot be prevented from closing.

**Note**

> While a window can be explicitly closed through mechanisms provided in
>   the non-client and client areas, a window can also be implicitly
>   closed as a result of behavior in other parts of the application or
>   Windows, including the following:
>
> - A user logs off or shuts down Windows.
> - A window's owner closes.
> - The main application window is closed and ShutdownMode is OnMainWindowClose.
> - Shutdown is called.

## All Window Lifetime Events

The following illustration shows the sequence of the principal events in the lifetime of a window.

[image]

The following illustration shows the sequence of the principal events in the lifetime of a window that is shown without activation (ShowActivated is set to false before the window is shown).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this work-around by accident. I happened to create another window in my code and therefore did not see the issue of Unloaded Event not firing in WPF.

> ```
> public partial class Window1 : Window
> {
>     public Window1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>
>         new Window(); //<-- this will make Unloaded Event to trigger in WPF
>     }
> }
> ```

The work-around also works in MVVM pattern!

**Ignore the rest of the code below if you don't do MVVM pattern.**

XAML
(Requires reference to System.Windows.Interactivity)

> ```
> <Window xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
>
>   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
>       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded">
>           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.WindowUnLoadEventHandler,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType {x:Type Window}}}"/>
>       </i:EventTrigger>
>   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
> </Window>
> ```

Code behind

> ```
>     public ICommand WindowUnLoadEventHandler
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (_windowUnload == null)
>             {
>                 _windowUnload = new MyDelegateCommand(ExecuteWindowUnLoadEventHandler);
>             }
>             return _windowUnload;
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void ExecuteWindowUnLoadEventHandler(object parameter)
>     {
>         //Do your thing
>     }
> ```

MyDelegateCommand

> ```
> public class MyDelegateCommand : ICommand
> {
>     private readonly Action<object> _execute;
>
>     public MyDelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
>     {
>         this._execute = execute;
>     }
>
>     public void Execute(object parameter)
>     {
>         _execute?.Invoke(parameter);
>     }
>
>     public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
> }
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this works only because creating a window instance will add it as "open" window of the app and therefore the app will not close properly